# Помогите понять выражение "Покушение на убийство"

Tags: грамотная-речь

Простите заранее, что возвращаюсь к уже заданному вопросу: "Покушение на убийство"!
Хочу обратить ваше внимание на тот факт, что по смыслу само это выражение является полным парадоксом того, что на самом деле оно должно означать!
Уточним для начала, что такое само "покушение"!
Покушение - это процесс, действие или попытка совершить какое-либо действие в отношении кого-то или чего-то, в результате чего у кого-то или чего-то могут быть "нехорошие" последствия! В данном случае, поскольку речь идёт о убийстве, человек может быть лишен жизни!
Далее!
Смотрите!
Кто-то умышленно лишает человека жизни, то есть совершает убийство! А кто-то, заступаясь, не даёт злоумышленнику его убить, совершая действия, предотвращающие само убийство, то есть он покушается на само убийство! Получается, что согласно закону этого человека, несмотря на то, что он спас человека, надо наказать, так как он покусился на убийство?!
Как это понять?!
У нас что, убийство охраняется законом?!
Согласитесь, что это бред полнейший! Как можно пытаться нанести какой-либо вред убийству, то есть покуситься на убийство?!
Может, всё-таки правильнее, как было раньше, выражение "покушение на жизнь"?

Answer (score 3):

Нужно понять и принять, что у слова *покушение* (покушение на что-л.) есть как минимум два смысла:

- действие (как преступная попытка), направленное на что-л., на какой-либо **объект**, например *покушение на жизнь*;
- попытка совершить некое (преступное, трудное) **действие**, например *покушение на убийство, на кражу, на смелый шаг.*

Answer (score 0):

**Может всё-таки правильнее, как было раньше...**

Раньше, как и сейчас, учили пользоваться словарями — они для того и предназначены, чтобы обогащать свой словарный запас и улучшать понимание. А обилием восклицательных знаков этого не достичь.

[Вот здесь](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/954146) со ссылкой на словарь Ушакова (который "раньше") сказано следующее:

> **ПОКУШЕНИЕ**, покушения, ср. Действие по гл. покуситься-покушаться.
>   *Покушение на убийство. Покушение на кражу.*

В современных словарях выражение **покуситься на убийство** зафиксировано у Ожегова, например.

Answer (score 0):

Совсем извратили все выражения и понятия,перевернули все с ног на голову,покушение на убийство,что за бред собачий,этого воообще не может быть.Покушение на жизнь,на человека,на богатство и т.д. но только не на убийство......это даже обьяснить невозможно и кто это вообще придумывает вот такие маразматические словосочетания.....!!!!!!!

Comment: Возможно это какой-то древний канцеляриат, по-типу "предложение о сотрудничестве". Или просто один дурак сказал, а второй повторил - так и пошло в словари.

Comment: А вообще я сейчас подумал, в ответе М_Г что-то есть...